# How to show information based on how it was accessed

Tags: php

I need to have the page so if they click on someones name and it takes them to the page it will show the clicked person's information and if they try to access the page any other way it will show their own information.

I have a profile page called profiles.php. They can access the page itself two ways, clicking the profile button or clicking someones name that will lead them to their profiles page. The page uses variable $current to fill in the information. What's a better way of doing this?

$_GET['id'] is from clicking on someone else's name.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $current = $_GET['id'];

}elseif(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    $current = $_SESSION['Id'];
}
```

Here's an example of what I'm currently using if a user doesn't get to the page by clicking someone's name:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
            if(isset($_SESSION['Id'])){
        echo '
            <ul>
                <button id="button" type="button">Edit Page</button>
            </ul>';}
        }
```

Comment: Is something not working for you? Why are you looking for a better way?

Comment: The problem is if someone enters the page from another way, like bookmarked for example, they will be able to edit that persons information.

Comment: Ask them to login or for some other form of authentication.

Comment: _“they will be able to edit that persons information”_ – that is something you first and foremost need to check for / prevent at the moment when you are actually _processing_ the submitted data. Everyone who knows what your form looks like can send you data in that same format, from _anywhere_. They would not even have to use a “form”, anything that can make HTTP requests would do.